# 'TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, moviepy

I'm getting this error every time I'm trying to upload video file, and I think the problem is come from the `moviepy` library that I'm using to cut every video that are higher than 10 minute.

the error: `AttributeError at /CreateVideo 'TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'`

views:

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def create_video(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        video = request.FILES['video']
        banner = request.FILES['banner']

        video_file = video
        video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_file.temporary_file_path())
        duration = video_clip.duration
        video_clip.close()
        if duration > 600: # 10 minute in seconds
            raise ValidationError('the video cannot be longer than 10 minute')
        return video_file

        new_video = Video.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            title=title,
            video=video,
            banner=banner
        )
        new_video.save()
        return redirect('Video')

    return render(request, 'video/create_video.html')
```

models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='banner')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Future User**:

The error message indicates that the `TemporaryUploadedFile object does not have a get() method`. This is likely because the `temporary_file_path()` method is returning a temporary file path string instead of an actual file object.

To fix this issue, change the `video_clip` initialization line from:

```
video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_file.temporary_file_path())
```

to:

```
video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_file)
```

But using that method would return an error:

```
'TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

To fix this issues you need to check if the file type of the video uploaded is supported by the library you are using (in this case, `VideoFileClip` from `moviepy`). You can also check if the file is being uploaded correctly by checking its file size or by printing out its contents like this:

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

def create_video(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        video = request.FILES.get('video')
        banner = request.FILES.get('banner')

        if video:
            video_type = video.content_type.split('/')[0]
            if video_type != 'video':
                raise ValidationError('File is not a video')
            video_ext = video.name.split('.')[-1]
            if video_ext not in ['mp4', 'avi', 'mov']:
                raise ValidationError('Unsupported video format')

            video_clip = VideoFileClip(video.temporary_file_path())
            duration = video_clip.duration
            video_clip.close()
            if duration > 600: # 10 minute in seconds
                raise ValidationError('the video cannot be longer than 10 minute')

            new_video = Video.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                title=title,
                video=video,
                banner=banner
            )
            new_video.save()
            return redirect('Video')
        else:
            raise ValidationError('No video file uploaded')

    return render(request, 'video/create_video.html')
```

[moviepy Docs](https://moviepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/ref.html)